# Positioning of segmented lines and annotated text in a bar chart with categorical horizontal variables in R

Tags: r, annotations, segment

The question can be described with a MWE as follows:

```
    df <- data.frame(Team = c("A", "B", "C"), Score = c(5, 8, 10)) 
    plot <- ggplot(df, aes(Team, Score)) + 
          geom_bar(stat = "identity")  ## plot the bar chart showing differences between teams

    ### In the following, I would like to add segmented lines between any two bars. 
    segments_AB <- data.frame(x0 = c("A", "A", "B"),   
                            y0 = c(5, 9, 9),
                            x1 = c("A", "B", "B"),
                            y1 = c(9, 9, 8)) 
    segments_AC <- data.frame(x0 = c("A", "A", "C"),   
                            y0 = c(5, 11, 11),
                            x1 = c("A", "C", "C"),
                            y1 = c(11, 11, 10))

    plot_segment <- plot + geom_segment(data = segments_AB, aes(x = x0, y = y0, xend = x1, yend = y1), show.legend = F) +
           geom_segment(data = segments_AC, aes(x = x0, y = y0, xend = x1, yend = y1), show.legend = F)
    plot_segment
```

Now, the problem is that the two segmented lines overlap on top of bar A which is shown in the following picture:
[image]

This is mainly because the horizontal axis is a categorical variable and I cannot shift the line by adding or subtracting some values.

Question: How do I make the AB line and AC line separate from each other?

In addition, I also want to add some text near each segmented line, but I can only add on top of one of the bars as follows:

```
    annotation <- data.frame(
        x = c("A", "B"),
        y = c(6, 9),
        label = c("p = 0.38", "p = 0.02")
    )

    plot_segment + geom_text(data = annotation, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), size = 2)
```

Question: How can I add annotations near the center of the horizontal part of each segmented line?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You don't need to use `"A", "B"` etc for the x values of your annotations - try setting it to 1.5 and 2.

Comment: As far as I can see, `geom_segment()` doesn't allow an x dodge or jitter in a useful way (the end points are fixed).  It may be worth trying `geom_linerange()`, or sticking with `geom_segment()` and setting the x coordinates to e.g. 1.1 for one segment, 0.9 for the other.  Rather manual and fiddly but might work as a one off.

Comment: @Paul Stafford Allen Thanks a lot for your comment. For `geom_linerange()`, I do not find the solution with it and will try later on. For `geom_segment`, how to set the x coordinates to different values for different bars? I would like to remain the labels of each bar below x-axis unchanged. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `segments_AB <- data.frame(x0 = c(1, 1, 2), y0 = c(5, 9, 9), x1 = c(1, 2, 2), y1 = c(9, 9, 8)) 
segments_AC <- data.frame(x0 = c(0.98,0.98,3),    y0 = c(5, 11, 11), x1 = c(0.98,3,3), y1 = c(11, 11, 10))`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! I once tried using `x0 = c(0.33, 0.66, 1)` but it did not work. I was so stupid not trying to play with the numbers. Maybe you can provide the answer like this so that I can accept it. Thanks a lot again! If you do not bother to do it, I can write the answer instead of you and give the credit to you.

Comment: Feel free to put your working code as an answer and accept it, cheers!